# Возможно ли с помощью "Qt Creator" создать динамическую библиотеку на C? Не на C++, а именно на C!

Tags: dll, qtcreator, so

В "Microsoft Visual Studio" нужно просто поменять расширение файлов с "cpp" на "c", и тогда библиотека автоматически компилируется на C. А в "Qt Creator" это возможно вообще?

Comment: там при создании проекта вроде можно выбрать С или С++

Comment: файлы переименовать, по необходимости подкорректировать pro файл. И должно все работать.

Comment: @Lofectr, нет, при создании проекта можно выбрать библиотеку только на C++ создать